# Get the higher number in a group of meta tag names

Tags: jquery, meta-tags

I have a group of meta tags with a consistent name (session-1/2/3/4...etc). The group will be different every time depending on how many meta the user needed.

I am trying to get the higher number in that meta group and grab the content. In this example, will be grabbing "session-3" content.

Not too sure how to start.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<meta name="session-1" content="frist">
<meta name="session-2" content="second">
<meta name="session-3" content="third">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In plain js is simple enough.

```js
let resultElement, count = 0
document.querySelectorAll('meta').forEach(el => {
  // for each meta element
  let met = el.name.split('-')
  // split name into number and seassion
  if (met[0] === 'session' && parseInt(met[1]) > count) {
    count = parseInt(met[1]), resultElement = el
  }
  //if there is seassion in name and if number is bigger then previues save it in count and save result element
})

console.log(resultElement.content)
```

```html
<meta name="session-1" content="frist">
<meta name="session-2" content="second">
<meta name="session-3" content="third">
```

Comment: is there a way only to look at meta content "session-" as the index? just in case in the future, there are similar meta added to the template.

Comment: @YanMak sure, wait a min

Comment: @YanMak done...

Comment: @YanMak np, see the last edit, it is more readable